# how to solve error CRS-0223 resource has placement error in oracle RAC?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have error in oracle database 11g real application cluster , i have 2 nodes node1,node2
when i checked the services i found instance node2 is not running

```
> srvctl status database -d db

instance ins1 is runnig on node node1
instance inst2 is not running on node2
```

when i checked the services some services offline

```
>crs_stat -t 

ora.node2.gsd   target=offline state =offline 
ora.node2.ASM2.asm state=offline
ora.node2.inst2 state=offline
```

i tried to start the services by using the following command

```
>crs_start ora.node2.gsd
```

but always get this error

```
crs-0223 : resource has placement error
```

how to solve this error and startup instance on node 2 ?

Comment: not all necessary resources to start the instance and open the database on node2 are available. You have to check the logs of the clusterware stack. Without more infos nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted the servers and everything working fine without errors

I think the cluster connection between the nodes was lost and need to restart the nodes.

Answer (score -1):

If the error persists after restart, try this article, the suggestion is to recreate the serverpool.

```
$ srvctl status serverpool -detail
$ srvctl add serverpool -serverpool dbpool -servers "host01,host02"
$ srvctl add database -db dbname -oraclehome $ORACLE_HOME -dbtype RAC -policy AUTOMATIC -serverpool namepool
$ srvctl config serverpool
```

Full explanation: https://wadhahdaouehi.tn/2019/12/bug-while-creating-new-administrator-manager-rac-12cr1-while-we-have-one/